# Async Await Gives Syntax Error Even when code Is correct

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have very simple code as below .

Function ls has async keyword and it returns Promise.

But , calling const `val = await ls()` gives below error.

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

Can anybody pleasse help me why this error is coming as :

1. The function ls has async keyword
2. It also returns a Promise

Further more , using then clause like below , it works fine

```
ls().then(val => console.log(val)).catch(e => e)
```

But below code doesn't work

```
   async function ls() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve('Print Output !!')
        });
    }
    
    const val = await ls()
    console.log(val)
```

Comment: Error is self-descriptive that *SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules*

Comment: await must be inside an async function

Comment: Is the code `await ls()` inside an async function or at the top level of a module? No, it's not. Therefore, it's not valid. Therefore, the code is not correct. Therefore the error message you saw was very precise and accurate in describing what the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
async function ls() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve('Print Output !!')
    });
}

// Way 1
async function test() { //function created for "await ls()"
    const val = await ls(); //this await requires async
    console.log("Way 1 " + val)
}
test();

// Way 2
(async function() {
    const val = await ls();
    console.log("Way 2 " + val)
})();
```